# Is it possible to use Export-ModuleMember with PowerShell filters

Tags: powershell

Say I have a filter defined in a PowerShell module:

```
filter OddNumbers {
  $value = $_
  $value | ? {($_ % 2)}
}
```

First, is it possible to export this filter using `Export-ModuleMember`? Second, if it is possible, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Export-modulemember -function OddNumbers
```

A filter is a special kind of function so this should work.